# Is it possible to change the answer swipe direction on Android 4.3, Motorola Moto G, or Samsung Galaxy S4?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-4, motorola-moto-g

I have a problem. My personal phone is a Samsung Galaxy S4 Android 4.2.2. I just got a new company phone which is a Motorola Moto G Android 4.3.

The problem is that if I swipe left when answering a call on Samsung it answers the phone. If I swipe left on the Motorola it ignores the call. Needless to say, I keep ignoring people on my business phone.

I need to figure out a way to change the direction of the answer swipe on one of them, preferably the Moto G since I'm already used to the Samsung way but I will settle for changing it on the Samsung if need be.

Comment: You could install a different dialler and see if it works the way you want or can be customised. https://play.google.com/store/search?q=dialer  Have a try of a few.

Answer (score 1):

I know that Android 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3 don't allow that by default (i.e, there is no setting for it.) You could, however, get another dialer or locker app. GO Locker is both a great locker and dialer, but it can get annoying, as it sometimes needs you to answer the Android OS dialer screen as well.